# PHP login form not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I am trying to create simple log in form, every time i click on submit button it goes to other page, even if my log in info is not correct. Here is my code, can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks!

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location="index2.php";</script>';
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include('connection.php');

$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pass = md5($_POST['password']);
if($user && $pass) {
$sql="SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE username = '" . $user . "' and password = '" . $pass . "'";
if (!$q=mysql_query($sql))
{
echo "<p>Error</p>" . mysql_query();
die();
}
if (mysql_num_rows($q)==0)
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Username i password incorrect!");     window.location="login.php";</script>';
} 
else {
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('everything works')</script>";
}
} else {
echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Fill out both fields!')</script>";
}
}
?>

<head>
<?php require("connection.php") ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">  
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
Password:&nbsp <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="LOGIN" name="submit" class="button" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

connection.php

```
<?php
$mysql_server = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_db = "comment";
if (!$db=mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)) {
die ("<p>Failed to connect</p>");
}
if (!mysql_select_db($mysql_db, $db))
{
die ("<p>Wrong database</p>");
} else {
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION='utf8_unicode_ci'");
}
?>
```

index2.php - just for testing if it works

```
<p>Welcome</p>
```

Comment: the obvious questions is, is the code in the first part from  a page named index2.php ( instead of login.php ), that is where you are sending the form, according to the action attribute of the form?

Comment: This is for learning purposes I hope, yes?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I believe it _must_ be

Comment: @Mr.Smith *Scary.* - MD5, shudder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question, `index2.php` file just contains a sample HTML text. You have `action` attribute set to this file, what causes that all POST values from this form will be sent to this script so this is the reason, why you got redirected on this file even data was incorrect.

```
<form action="index2.php" method="POST">
```

Should be

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Comment: Yes after I wrote that answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks i have changed that,but now it doesn't go on that page, now it look like the connection to database is wrong, because when I enter  a user that exists in database it shows that i have entered wrong user.

Comment: @user3734349 no, it doesn't go, because you don't have any redirection on success, just javascript alert. /Edit this redirect won't work on first login, only if you refresh login page.

Comment: Yeah, but it show alert that I have username and pass incorrect, not the alert where everything is ok

Comment: Yeah it just doesn't accept data that isnt added with md5 in phpmyadmin, i will change that now, thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark it as accepted to let the others know that this question was solved. @user3734349 :)

Answer (score 0):

I would also change this line

```
if (!$db=mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)) {
    die ("<p>Failed to connect</p>");
}
```

To

```
if (false === ( $db = mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_password))) {
    die ("<p>Failed to connect</p>");
}
```

Also change this one

```
if (!$q=mysql_query($sql)){


}
```

to

```
if (false === ( $q = mysql_query($sql)) ){
  ...
```

I haven't really tested this but you might be 'muddying' up the variable `$q` your query result with the `!` not right there, possibly telling php that not `$q` equals your.  To test this do `var_export( $q )` then if its false separate it  from the if statement

```
     $q=mysql_query($sql);
     if( $q ) ... etc.
```

I always do them ( inline assignment within an if ) like I put above because then it is clear that you are assigning `$q` and then testing it.